# Paginator in laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I have something like this:

```
$paginated = Paginator::make($n, count($n), Input::get('limit') ?: '10');
```

at the top of your file. `use Paginator;` 
Error:

```
Class 'Paginator' not found
```

All In my Laravel 5.

Comment: You need `use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;` per the docs. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::make()

Comment: Read its API docs. They moved the making into the constructor. You can't just try L4 code and expect it to be fine. http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html

Comment: oke, and what I should do?

Comment: Read the Laravel 5 docs

Answer (score 2):

Actually before asking the question, you should have read laravel docs or had took look on laracasts. There is a free video on it. But here's the solution to your problem:

At the top of the file, add this line,

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
```

Just after adding this line most of your problem will be solved. If the problem still continues, use something like

```
$paginated = Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::make($n, count($n), Input::get('limit') ?: '10');
```

Hope so this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination) pagination is easy in Laravel 5 but different than it was in Laravel 4. What you should be trying is something like this to retrieve the model: (User model for example)

```
$users = User::paginate(15);
return view('users.index', compact('users'));
```

In your view you will do something like: (this assumes blade is used)

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  {{ $user->name }}
@endforeach
{!! $users->render() !!}
```

Comment: Hopefully you were able to figure this out by now given the link to the documentation in the comment. I will let you use the docs to see what else is possible. Please learn to use documentation. It is fine to ask questions but attempt to understand the docs first or you will find software development very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
```

And then you can just call a ->render method of chaining call at your model